# Xcode 12 Build and run project for simulator, But got a permission issue

Tags: simulator, xcode12

When I upgraded to Xcdoe 12 and build the previous app project, And then I got an error when running the simulator, it seemed to be a permission problem. I also went to File> Get Info for what the error said, but no exception was found.

Any ideas?

========================

The following is the error content:

Details

```
The file “***” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 257
Failure Reason: You don’t have permission.
Recovery Suggestion: To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.
User Info: {
  NSFilePath = "/Users/momo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/***-dxvphugocaepzfaicmcbykxrlgrt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/***.app";
}
-

The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 13
Failure Reason: Permission denied
```

System Information

macOS Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G2021)
Xcode 12.0.1 (17220)

Comment: Same here. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Any updates? Im also having same issue.